# MySQL select datetime

Tags: mysql, datetime

Just to understand the basics of MySQL: while the following works:

```
SELECT DATE('2010-01-01');
```

the following doesn't:

```
SELECT DATETIME('2010-01-01 12:34:56');
```

It raises the following:

```
ERROR 1064 (42000): You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '('2010-01-01 12:34:56')' at line 1
```

I wonder why it is so, as the documentation for `DATE` and `DATETIME` are respectively as follows:

> MySQL retrieves and displays `DATE` values in 'YYYY-MM-DD' format.
>
> MySQL retrieves and displays `DATETIME` values in 'YYYY-MM-DD HH:MM:SS' format.

I know that I do not need to "cast" a string into a `DATETIME` in order to insert it into a table. I am just wondering why this is not consistent.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

mysql doesn't provide datetime function.

All it provide is **[TIMESTAMP()](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_timestamp)**

```
SELECT TIMESTAMP('2010-01-01 12:34:56');
```

**[fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/d41d8/36303)**

Comment: I see... I wasn't aware that `DATE` is a function as well! I just thought it's a type, and that `DATE(...)` is a cast call.

Answer (score 0):

Yup there is no DATETIME or similar name function in mysql.

Also `DATE('2003-12-31 01:02:03')` will only return the Date part in it.

Either use `TIMESTAMP('2003-12-31 12:10:05')`  OR

`STR_TO_DATE('5/15/2012 8:06:26 AM', '%c/%e/%Y %r')` if you want to convert String to DateTime.